# Linking Excel to Email. Send bulk emails

Tags: vba, excel, email

I'm trying to send emails in bulk (and I thought Excel would be a good option for this). Basically trying to bridge an Excel file to an Email address and fill in 3 or 4 spaces automatically. For example: Hello [Insert cell A1] blah blah blah [Insert cell B1].

Just wanted to get an idea of where to start for this. (I understand that this will require some VBA)

Comment: Check out Ron de Bruin's blog: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm

Comment: Why not use Microsoft Word's mail merge? This will be much easier for you to learn than it will be if you haven't used VBA before. Further, VBA doesn't make it as easy to send an email using VBA where fields need to be edited (at least not compared to mail merge in word).

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3560-excel-send-personalized-email.html

This link outlines a VBA code that i used. For some reason when i run it, it just opens web browsers instead of sending the mails through my outlook. I think this is because it is not connected to my outlook?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic template you can use:

```
Option Explicit

Dim IE As Object

Sub Send_Email()
  Dim eSubject, eTo, eBody As String
  Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant
  eSubject = "Example of how to send email using VBA"
  eTo = "your_username@gmail.com"

  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
  With sht:
    eBody = "Hello " & .Cells(1, "A").value & " blah blah blah " & .Cells(1, "B").value
  End With

  On Error GoTo debugHere
  Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)
  With Mail_Single
   .Subject = eSubject
   .To = eTo
   .body = eBody
   .send
  End With

debugHere:
  If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description 
End Sub
```

To send multiple emails using this template all you do is to place a for loop around the code that starts with setting the Mail_Object and ends with the end with statement.

Comment: Thanks man, I was using the template in https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3560-excel-send-personalized-email.html

I was wondering if the VBA code itself is connected to my outlook? cause it just opens up web browsers.

Comment: It works through outlook - at least it's configured to do that on my machine.  Don't know how that'll work with mail clients other than outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail6.htm